# Hide WiFi status icon on CM 12

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, notification-icons

I don't want to anyone to see the connected WiFi symbol on my phone status bar, can you please help me?

I have Galaxy Note II with CyanogenMod 12.1.

Answer (score 0):

You may install Xposed framework and then some xposed module to customise status bar. The module Xblast tools may work. Check for the option to hide the WiFi icon. (If such exact option is not present, you may try to change its color to fully transparent.)